# Adding multiple views inside a region

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm new with Sencha EXTjs and want to now how I can combine multiple views inside one viewport (something like include a file inside a div element with PHP).

My viewport file contains an South, Center and West region and I want to add a view which contains a form for this section.

Answer (score 0):

The layouts have tons of interesting quirks that make one more convienent than the other , so you should definitely read up on them:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/exploring-the-layout-system-in-ext-js-5-and-sencha-touch

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html (this is for extjs4, but I find it easier to visualize with).

The "border" layout (which I assume your using because it is the only layout that uses the "region" property) needs a "center" region, but all other regions are optional. You could just have a "north" and a "center" (or "center" and a "south"). For example, you can see there is no "east" in the border layout in the second link.